# What is the name of this function, $f(x) = \frac{1}{\exp(-kx)+1}$?

Tags: exponential-function

What is this function, $f(x) = \frac{1}{\exp(-kx)+1}$, where $k$ is a constant, called?

Comment: It is a [logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)

Answer (score 4):

It's a special case of the [logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function).